# How to insert the value in disabled text field using protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I'm trying to insert the values against the disabled text field. I tried with below approach but unable to send the input values. Can anyone help me?

HTML:

```
<input class="input-text" _ngcontent-c11="" disabled="" name="filename" ng-reflect-name="filename" ng-reflect-is-disabled="" type="text">
```

Script:
I tried with the below scripts:

```
element(by.css('input[name="filename"]')).sendKeys("Welcome");
```

Error Message:
**InvalidElementStateError: invalid element state**

Answer (score 2):

You can use `javascriptexecutor` in protractor

You can use `setAttribute` function like below :-

```
browser.driver.executeScript("document.getElementById('start-date').setAttribute('value','01/10/2017')");
```

In above code value is attribute like name and 01/10/2017 is value you want to set.

OR

In protector the other way will be like:-

```
browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('attr', '10')",element);
```

In above code attr is attribute like name and 10 is value. change it as per your requirement.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Hi Thanks for your comment.. Yes I tried with that, The appropriate element attribute got changed. But in the UI I can't able to see the value. (i.e In UI level the field not displaying the value with I updated using setAttribute).

Comment: can you check bu manual enter the value and see which element having the value. Now pick the xpath of same element and then try. javascriptexecutor works directly by JS so It should work